# Python SQLite3: Strange NoneType issue when executing query twice in a row

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

So to preface this: the goal is to split a sqlite database into three shards through code. I have a majority of the background of storing and accessing the databases, but seem to have run into an issue trying to query more than one of those shards in a row to find a specific row. Code more than likely speaks for itself, so please look at it below.

```
def get_db():
"""Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
current application context.
"""
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if not hasattr(top, 'sqlite_db'):
        top.sqlite_db = [ sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_1, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES), sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_2, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES), sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_3, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) ]
        top.sqlite_db[0].row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        top.sqlite_db[1].row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        top.sqlite_db[2].row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return top.sqlite_db


def query_db(query, shard, args=(), one=False):
"""Queries the database and returns a list of dictionaries."""
    db = get_db()
    cur = db[shard].execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv


def get_user_id(username):
"""Convenience method to look up the id for a username."""
    rb = query_db('select user_id from user where username = ?', 1, [username], one=True)
    rv = query_db('select user_id from user where username = ?', 2, [username], one=True)
    return rv[0] if rv else None


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_database(exception):
"""Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if hasattr(top, 'sqlite_db'):
        top.sqlite_db[0].close()
        top.sqlite_db[1].close()
        top.sqlite_db[2].close()
```

I tried to include everything that may be needed. get_user_id is where I'm encountering an issue; it seems that calling into query_db twice in arrow is causing the problem below (it seems that it doesn't matter what they're assigned to either, as it encounters the same problem either way).

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If i remove either of the lines (whether it queries the right shard or not) it works. Whether there's an actual row in the database with that username shouldn't matter, since it is confirmed to return None when I remove on of the lines in get_user_id. The problem seems to arise from calling query_db twice in a row. This further leads me to believe that there's an issue with calling the db connection. Once again, I've tried to include everything that I believe to be relevant, but I can add anything else if this isn't enough.

EDIT 1:

Adding full traceback as requested.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.local/bin/flask", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Flask', 'console_scripts', 'flask')()
  File "/home/me/Desktop/project/flask/flask/cli.py", line 881, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/home/me/Desktop/project/flask/flask/cli.py", line 557, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Desktop/project/flask/flask/cli.py", line 412, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Desktop/project/flask/examples/minitwit/minitwit/mt_api.py", line 149, in dummy_command
    dummy_db()
  File "/home/me/Desktop/project/flask/examples/minitwit/minitwit/mt_api.py", line 143, in dummy_db
    rv = get_user_id('dbrewer5')
  File "/home/me/Desktop/project/flask/examples/minitwit/minitwit/mt_api.py", line 86, in get_user_id
    rv = query_db('select user_id from user where username = ?', 2, [username], one=True)
  File "/home/me/Desktop/project/flask/examples/minitwit/minitwit/mt_api.py", line 75, in query_db
    cur = db[shard].execute(query, args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Can you include the whole traceback, just to be sure the error really is coming from where you think it is?

Comment: @abarnert I've edited the post with the full traceback. The dummy calls are cli commands i was using to test everything.

Comment: The problem is in `db[shard]`, not in `rv[0]`, so you're looking in the wrong place. The question is how `get_db` returns `None` the second time you call it.

Comment: @abarnet Could you elaborate? The two calls to query_db are just examples. If you remove even one of those, then it functions as expected. Returning None is expected in this context because it would just mean that none of the databases contained that record.

Comment: The exception comes from the line `cur = db[shard].execute(query, args)`. That means that `NoneType` object is `db` (you're calling `__getitem__` on it with that `[shard]`). So that `rv[0]` is a red herring—the code doesn't even get that far. And, since you've done `db = get_db()` immediately before, that means `get_db()` must have somehow returned `None`. So what you need to debug is how _that_ happened.